# visibility from inside callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

The code I wrote below is part of the controller user.js

```
exports.login = function(req, res) {
var db = require('../db').tables;

//db.user.find(function(err, user) { console.log(user) });

switch (req.method) {
    default:
    case 'GET':
    break;
    case 'POST':
        db.user.find({username: req.body.username}, function(err, user) {

        });

        console.log(user);
    break;
}

res.render('user/login', {title: 'Login'});
};
```

The problem is the function **db.user.find** and I do not have available the variable **res** within the callback.

I have already tried several times to re-read the documentation mongoose to use a syntax more comfortable but nothing.

How do you advise me to change the code?

Sorry for bad English but I used Google. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the anonymous callback function for `find` is defined within the context of the `login` function, your callback already has access to `res` via closure.

```
...
db.user.find({username: req.body.username}, function(err, user) {
    // code here can reference res from the enclosing scope
    res.json(user);
});
...
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm an idiot, the `res.render()` overwriting the `render` inside the callback.

For this reason it did not work.
Thanks!